# Disable or remove all Console#WriteLine calls?

Tags: c#, .net

In my application I have a lot of `Console#WriteLine` or `Console#Write calls`. This are so many, that the application is really slower than necessary.

So I'm looking for an easy way to remove or at least disable all Console#WriteLine and `Console#Write` calls.

What's the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: In the future you may want to use [`#IF DEBUG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) or use the [ConditionalAttribute](http://weblogs.asp.net/tgraham/archive/2004/03/12/88682.aspx) and your own debug print method.

Comment: I'm already doing that, but at the start of the project I didn't do it.

Comment: Littering #IF DEBUG for Console.WriteLine in the app sounds like a bad idea to me...use a logging engine where you can tailor the level at runtime

Comment: @Aaron: Which is why I mentioned the ConditionalAttribute. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe Find&Replace function in any code editor?
For example find all

```
Console.WriteLine
```

and replace with

```
//Console.WriteLine
```

Comment: I thought about that but the problem is I would have a regex or something like that.

Comment: And then I have a lot of whitespace in the code because I would have to replace the call with " " or something like that.

Comment: Maybe what i wrote would be enough?

Comment: Hmm yes that could be a solution. I will do that if I cant find a simple solution to completely remove it.

Comment: If you just comment it you wouldn't need regexp and in case you need some day this WriteLine calls you will just uncomment them

Answer (score 29):

Here's a even quicker quick fix I implemented.

```
...
static int Main(String[] args)
{
...
#if !DEBUG
    Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null);
    Console.SetError(TextWriter.Null);
#endif
...
}
```

HTH

Comment: This is a better answer, because it does not require comment syntax, it does not require any changes in the code.. See my supplement answer below, use that when you want to switch off output only temporarily.

Answer (score 4):

To switch off **Console.WriteLine()** output in runtime *temporarily* use

```
     // backup the previous output handler connected to Console
     TextWriter backupOut = Console.Out;

     // activate a null handle
     Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null);

     // this console output will be invisible
     Console.WriteLine("Hidden output on Console.");

     // restore the previous handle
     Console.SetOut(backupOut);

     // this console output will be visible
     Console.WriteLine("Showing output on Console.");
```

Similarly, you can disable program **Debug.WriteLine()** output in runtime, also while compiling in Debug mode, by using a dummy TextWriterTraceListener, like so

```
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.IO;

 //...

 public class MyDummyListener: TextWriterTraceListener
 { }

 // ......

 [STAThread]
 static void Main()
 {
        // Back up the old one
        DefaultTraceListener[] debuglisteners = {(DefaultTraceListener) Debug.Listeners[0]};

        // Plug in dummy listener
        TextWriterTraceListener[] dummylisteners = {new MyDummyListener()};
        Debug.Listeners.Clear();
        Debug.Listeners.AddRange(dummylisteners);

        // this is an invisible debug message
        Debug.WriteLine("This one is invisible");

        // ..

        // to activate output again, plug in the previous listener
        Debug.Listeners.Clear();
        Debug.Listeners.AddRange(debuglisteners);
        Debug.WriteLine("This one is visible again");

  // ....
}
```

Note: I tested above code in .NET Framework 4.7.2 in Debug mode, using the Winforms platform.

Answer (score 3):

If they are non-essential (logging) then you should have used `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print()` to start with.

Luckily `WriteLine()` is compatible with `Debug.Print()` so that's an easy S&R. And fix some usings maybe.

Replacing `Console.Write()` might be a little trickier.

To be complete: The Debug.Print() statements can be turned on/off with a checkbox in project|Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple, non regex, Find/Replace dialog, and replace every `Console.WriteLine(` by [`Debug.WriteLine(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx).

You can then keep the possibility to track what was previously outputted directly to the console window, still optimizing performance in release mode.

Comment: Debug.WriteLine does not handle the same parameters.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: you're right. I keep my answer (it can be useful if in this precise case, the parameters were very basic, like just a single string every time), but I +1 your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, use the `Tools|Macros|Record temporary macro` option to record a macro that does a Find of "Console.Write", and deletes the line.  That is:

Ctrl+F to find "Console.Write"
then Ctrl+L to delete the line.

Save the macro and then run it against every file in the project that has the offending lines.

Should take about two minutes.

I would suggest, however, that you back up your source first.  Just in case.